# Selecting columns of dataframe where Lasso coefficient is nonzero

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I did LASSO regression with a data-set using scikit and pandas. I want to try to fit OLS to the features selected by LASSO. I have something like

```
lassomodel = LassoCV(alphas = [1, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0005]).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and

```
lassomodel.coef_
```

and I want to get the dataframe or numpy array with all the features whose LASSO coefficients is unequal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use boolean indexing on X_train where the coefficients are not equal to 0

If X_train is a numpy array then you do:

```
X_train[:,lassomodel.coef_!=0]
```

If X_train is a pandas dataframe, then you do:

```
X_train.iloc[:,lassomodel.coef_!=0]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error: TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None),array([ huge array of truth values]))' is an invalid key

Comment: adding .iloc works

X_train.iloc[:, lasso.coef_!=0]

Comment: @lgegre I thought X_train was an array, my bad, will add this option in the answer to make it clearer